# change dropdown button class on clicking dropdown items and page reloads

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to change the class of a dropdown button item after a user has clicked an item from the dropdown menu and the page reloads.

The below works unless the page refreshes.

```
$(".dropdown-content").on("click", function() {
 $('.dropbtn').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Is there a localstorage option I could use? I'm just learning about it.

I am currently using this to call back the text that appears in the drop down button:

```
$(".dropbtn").text(
localStorage.getItem("selected") 
? localStorage.getItem("selected")
: "Helpful Links"
);
$(".dropbtn").on("click", function () {
$(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("open");
});
$(".dropdown-content a").on("click", function () {
$(".dropbtn").text($(this).text());
localStorage.setItem("selected", $(this).text());
$(".dropdown-content").removeClass("open");
});
```

Many thanks to @RedApple for helping with that. It is working well - just wondering if I can set the .dropbtn class to active in a similar way when a .dropdown-content a item is clicked.

I have tried this but I do not think I am using it correctly because .dropbtn is not retaining the active class on page reload:

```
$(".dropdown-content").on("click", function() {
localStorage.setItem("active", $('.dropbtn').toggleClass('active'));
 $('.dropbtn').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You can store information in `localStorage` to persist across page loads, yes.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: I tried $(".dropdown-content").on("click", function() {
localStorage.setItem("active", $('.dropbtn').toggleClass('active'));
 $('.dropbtn').toggleClass('active');
});
$(".dropdown-content a").on("click", function() {
localStorage.getItem("active");
 $('.dropbtn').removeClass('active');
}); but I do not think I am using it correctly.

Comment: Please update the question to include your attempt and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected when you test/debug your code.

Comment: That first click handler doesn't make sense.  You're doing this twice: `$('.dropbtn').toggleClass('active')`  Which means it'll toggle twice, effectively returning to its original state.  And you're trying to store a jQuery object in `localStorage`.  Storing complex objects in `localStorage` won't work, it's meant for just storing *data* (as a string, basically).  It *looks like* you're essentially just randomly copying/pasting bits of code and hoping for the best.  Don't.  For any given operation you want to perform, test and debug specifically that operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work...

```
let isBtnClicked = localStorage.getItem("isBtnClicked")
? localStorage.getItem("isBtnClicked")
: false;
$(".dropbtn").addClass(
isBtnClicked
? "hovered" // YOUR CLASSNAME FOR CLICKED BTN GOES HERE
: ""
);
$(".dropbtn").text(
localStorage.getItem("selected")
? localStorage.getItem("selected")
: "Helpful Links"
);
$(".dropbtn").on("click", function () {
$(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("open");
isBtnClicked = !isBtnClicked;
localStorage.setItem("isBtnClicked", isBtnClicked);
});
$(".dropdown-content a").on("click", function () {
$(".dropbtn").text($(this).text());
localStorage.setItem("selected", $(this).text());
$(".dropdown-content").removeClass("open");
});
```